# Fitting add on blinds to rear door

Tags: doors, windows, blinds

I am trying to fit add on, enclosed blinds ([like these](https://www.homedepot.com/p/ODL-22-in-w-x-64-in-h-Add-On-Enclosed-Aluminum-Blinds-White-Steel-Fiberglass-Doors-with-Raised-Frame-Around-Glass-BWM226401/100656620)) to the rear door of my new home. I have not been able to find a set of blinds that fit appropriately and I am not sure why. I've returned 2 sets so far.

- Is this a non-standard door?
- Is there a type of enclosed blind that has the narrow clearance I need to fit it with the door hardware?
- Are there other, equally effective solutions for putting privacy blinds on this door?
- I want to avoid blinds that slap against the door when it is opened and closed.

**Window Frame Measurements:**

- Inside frame
- Vertical: 63 in. (approx)
- Horizontal: 21 in. (approx)
- Outside frame
- Vertical: 66 in.
- Horizontal: 23 3/4 in.
- Distance to hardware from frame
- Door handle: 1/2 in (approx)
- Deadbolt: 3/4 in (approx)

**Pictures:**

Full door frame:

[image: Rear door]

Inside vertical measurement:

[image: Inside vertical measurement]

Inside horizontal measurement:

[image: Inside horizontal measurement]

Outside vertical measurement:

[image: Outside vertical measurment]

Outside horizontal measurement:

[image: Outside horizontal measurement]

Handle to frame measurement:

[image: Door handle to frame]

Deadbolt to frame measurement:

[image: Deadbolt to frame]

Comment: The problem is that there's no "standard" glass opening size. You need a blind made for that specific brand of door, or you need a custom size.

Comment: A new door with the blind built in is 670.00 on Home Depot's web site = happy wife.   here a link to a retro fit window. https://www.amazon.com/ODL-Blinds-Raised-Frame-Doors/dp/B00AIVT6QU/ref=pd_sbs_201_2/136-7652493-0660018?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=B00AIVT6QU&pd_rd_r=e08827bc-6639-4eef-83cb-fd3248178ae8&pd_rd_w=us74Q&pd_rd_wg=iI2Mk&pf_rd_p=7cd8f929-4345-4bf2-a554-7d7588b3dd5f&pf_rd_r=RMNYJ7HS0DZJH37WP27P&psc=1&refRID=RMNYJ7HS0DZJH37WP27P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Self answering! I finally brought my measurements with me to Home Depot and sure enough they had what I needed! I wasn’t sure it was going to fit during the installation but the blinds turned out to be perfect, real snug.

In my circumstances I needed to order 24”x66” blinds (which seem obvious). I should have brought my measurements and pictures the first time!

Here are the blinds installed:
[image: Blinds installed]

And here is the packaging for the ODL product I ultimately needed:

[image: ODL Box]

Thanks again for the help everyone!

**Edit (2 years later):** I'd just like to note that these blinds failed within about a year of being installed; they no longer smoothly retract within the frame. I took it apart and attempted to fix it but it didn't really work. I'm going to be replacing them with 24x72in. faux wooden blinds this weekend. Most faux wooden blinds come with small clips that can be installed to hold the bottom of the blind; this keeps them from slapping.

Comment: Nice, looks just like the one i linked too except the dimensions.  What was the cost ?

Comment: Yes I think it's almost identical! Thank you for your link, it got me pointed in the right direction :) It cost $137 USD with taxes. Not too bad!

Comment: Sorry to hear they failed so soon. I would think that any blind intended for installation on a door would include clips to hold the bottom in place.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to have the blinds cut to size, many home stores even big box can cut custom sizes. To avoid blind slap some blinds come with lower mounts that hold the bottom bar in place. This limits the blind to twisting them to horizontal for open or verticals for closed. 
Some higher end blinds actually have rails that contain the blind and bottom and keep it in place. And can be raised and lowered

Answer (score 1):

> I want to avoid blinds that slap against the door when it is opened
>   and closed.

You could use normal blinds, but [velcro](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B073XS3CHW) the bottom of the blinds to the doorframe. It's mildly more work than normal blinds, but it eliminates the slapping and is easy enough to detach and raise.

Going in a different direction, another idea would be applying [privacy window film](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B072FP1M4H) to the door's window. That gives you privacy but doesn't do much for sun glare.

Comment: You can buy a window replacement for that door that has the blinds built inside of it between the two panes of glass and they are actuated by a lever in the trim of the window.

Comment: @Rob Elliot I appreciate that recommendation!

Comment: @AlaskaMan I will look into that! It might be more expensive than finding add on blinds, but the wife is going crazy because I'm using a trash bag over the window at the moment :P I'll look into it for sure!